# How to find child position of its parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

When I click on an element, I want to figure out its child position by its parent (using JavaScript).

Can anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: please, can you add your html and js code you have

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to grab a handle to the parent, then use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index of the element within it's [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) array.

```js
function findPos(el) {
  const i = Array.from(el.parentNode.children).indexOf(el)

  console.log(i) 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="findPos(this)">Click Me</button>
  <button onclick="findPos(this)">Click Me</button>
  <button onclick="findPos(this)">Click Me</button>
  <button onclick="findPos(this)">Click Me</button>
  <button onclick="findPos(this)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```